# How to only check for a root key in JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP script that query an API, get a JSON as response, and should check for the existence and content of a `"error": {}"` key in the JSON response.

My problem is that the JSON response is very huge, and `json_decode` take like 1mn to decode it (I wont even talk about the memory consumtion of that operation).

I dont need the whole JSON to be decoded, I just need that one precise root key.

I could create my own function but is there any existing way to do this ? I searched but found nothing that solve my case.

**Thank you in advance for your answer !**

Comment: Check the string directly with a string function to find any occurrence of `"error": {`, then you take whatever is after that until the next `}` and json_decode it...

Comment: json_decode takes a depth argument. I don't know how the json is structured, but if it has a lot of nested elements then playing around with the depth variable could significantly speed up the decoding process. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @Alberto that would not ensure that this key was on the root level. Plus, maybe that item itself is an object, so you would be dealing with multiple { and } pairs before you reached the end of that object. And maybe the (text) content might also contain { or }, which would complicate the whole thing even more …

Comment: @DirkScholten can this really speed up the decoding process? I would assume it still has to go down all the “branches” to properly parse the structure, and that at most the memory imprint of the resulting data structure would be lighter …

Comment: @misorude, yay, mine is a really ugly, raw suggestion.

Comment: If you control both sides of this, then my suggestion would be to return ONLY the error if there is an error (after all, what are you going to do with the 'big' data if you find the "error": {}" anyway?).  Can't get much faster than that...

Comment: @DirkScholten I just tried the `$depth` param of `json_decode` but it make the function returl `null` and the `json_last_error` return an error (`json_last_error_msg` return `Maximum stack depth exceeded`) so this parameter can't be used to limit the recursion at decoding but only to ensure that the given JSON isn't too deep...

Comment: @CFPSupport In fact I'm trying to solve an issue in a script provided by Esri (https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/blob/master/PHP/proxy.php#L938) to proxify their servers and allow the exposure of a sub-part of the api to the client without giving any credentials, so I dont control the server & API implementation =/